# How can I hide user_id from URL using yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I am using the yii framework and have different user accounts. When I want to have a look at the view page of user 4 I have to enter an url like `www.mydomain.com/user/4` for update I have `www.mydomain.com/user/update/4`.

Is there a way so that I can hide the user id from the url line?

How can I set a route like `www.mydomain.com/user/username` and `www.mydomain.com/user/update/username`? Do I have to modify the routes?

What if the `username` contains an @ symbols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each user has a unique username, you can describe a route that doesn't show their user id by putting this custom routing rule in `config/main`:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'rules' => array(
        'user/<username:\S+>' => 'users/view',
    )
)
```

The `\S+` should accept "@". Then pass that username to `controllers/UsersController` like so:

```
public function actionView($username) {...}
```

Instead of `www.mydomain.com/user/update/username` I would use `www.mydomain.com/user/<username>/update` and put this in the above urlManager rules array:

```
'user/<username:\S+>/update' => 'users/update',
```

and this in `UsersController`:

```
public function actionUpdate($username) {...}
```

You can also generate a unique, random number for each user before creation and route based on that number.

Comment: So you will use both rules?
'user/<username:\S+>' => 'users/view', 
'user/<username:\S+>/update' => 'users/update',

i.e., one rule for each action? 
does the second rule really hide the user name? www.mydomain.com/user//update

Comment: I think you need both rules if you want custom routing. There might be some clever way to combine into 1, but I'm not sure. (Custom routes slow Yii's performance.)

Made a typo for the second rule. The url for the 2nd rule won't hide the username. It should be `www.mydomain.com/user/<username>/update`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to encrypt your id before passing it. And decrypt it when you reach there. There are many ways of generating such random/encrpted ids. For more security you should not give name like 'user', that you did. Try to modify that even. Hope you got the point...:)

Comment: can you give an example for such encrypted ids?

Comment: here are some examples you can look into => [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).  Also you can make your own encryption function in a model of your project.