# How to hide everything(id) in the URL in the browser except the site name and controller name in yii?

Tags: url, yii

How to hide/encrypt everything(id) in the URL in the browser except the site name and controller name? 
I think UrlManager can do it, but I don't know how ? need url mapping similar in [ROR](http://rubyonrails.org)

my url manager code

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        //'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=> false,
        'rules'=>array(

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

I like to add a random number between every action(for secure my urls)

ROR eg:

```
   map.connect 'by/:develop_name',
    :controller => 'developer',
    :action => 'builder_projects'
```

Please explain step by step.

couple if links I found relate to this

[LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507252/how-can-i-hide-user-id-from-url-using-yii-framework)
[LINk2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152956/url-rewriting-with-yii-framework)

Comment: Try with this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify your application routes appropriately. Before continuing, you should read the [URL management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) chapter of the Yii guide.

What you want to do is use [named parameters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters) in your rules, which means that the rule definition would look like this:

```
'by/<id:\w+>' => 'developer/builder_projects'
```

This rule takes a URL of the form `http://site.com/index.php/by/42` and routes it to the controller `developer`, action `builder_projects` with the parameter `id` equal to whatever 42 (this is what the regular expression `\w+` matches).

Routes are specified in your [application configuration file](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-configuration) as parameters to the [`urlManager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager) component:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules'     => array(
        'by/<id:\w+>' => 'developer/builder_projects'
        // more rules
    ),
),
```

Comment: This won't encrypt or hide his params though.

Comment: @MattHarrison: The RoR example given does not do so either, so I believe this is what the OP wants. And regarding "encryption", simply using an opaque identifier instead of an integer is not encrypting anything either. The only thing achieved is that the user can't type in a value with a good chance of that value corresponding to an existing resource, but you don't need any encryption to do that: just use an opaque identifier like a GUID instead of an integer.

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood. I thought he just wanted an ad-hoc way of concealing the true resource identifiers from the user.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is define a helper function which symmetrically encrypts/decrypts:

```
class Helper {

    public static function myCrypt($data, $decrypt = false){
        //Logic to encrypt/decrypt

        return $result;
    }
}
```

and then when you create urls you can do:

```
$this->createUrl("myRoute", array("secret_id" => Helper::myCrypt($secret_id)));
```

and then in the controller action this resolves to you can do this:

```
public function actionMyRoute($secret_id){
    $secret_id = Helper::myCrypt($secret_id, true);

   //Do what you need to do with the decrypted id
}
```

Just make sure your encryption method returns a url safe string.